# Using USB Drive as Boot Drive and Storage

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot, partition, google-chrome-os

I have a 32GB USB drive that I am trying to use as both a boot drive for a ChromeOS version available from [here](http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/), and to use the remaining space on the drive as I normally would, just for storage to be accessed via Windows or hopefully the ChromeOS.

I've tried partitioning it in various ways using EaseUS, but every time I've written the ChromeOS image to a partition with the Win32DiskImager, I can't access the larger partition I want as storage.

I feel like I'm missing something major here, can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Win32DiskImager overwrite all contents including partioning information on USB device by disk image.  This is why you lost other partion you had made.

Comment: This question is better suited for [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

when you make a bootable usb using ChromeOs image

```
 When does resizing occur?
Partition resizing is initiated by the system, not by the user.
```

[refer here for more information](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/partition-resizing)